# Design flaw? One page website, tabs that load content

Tags: html, ajax, web-applications

I have a simple web application with a number of tabs.  The tab content's gets loaded using AJAX when the user clicks on the tab.  However, it takes `< 1s` to load some of the tabs so from the user's point of view, there is no content at first (just empty inputs that will be populated via AJAX)

```
$('#my-tab').on('click', function() {
   // load content
});

$('#another-tab').on('click', function() {
   // load some different content
});
```

To solve the problem I can:

1) Use some AJAX spinner to inform the user that there is content but it's about to be loaded

2) Use HTML forms instead so content is loaded without AJAX

What is the correct/best/common solution?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [good article](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/) that summaries what you ask for.

> There are 3 main time limits (which are determined by human perceptual
>   abilities) to keep in mind when optimizing web and application
>   performance.

Based on an approximate time it takes to load the content for your average user, you can apply this practice :

> 0.1 second is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is reacting instantaneously, meaning that no special feedback is
>   necessary except to display the result.
>
> 1.0 second is about the limit for the user's flow of thought to stay uninterrupted, even though the user will notice the delay. Normally,
>   no special feedback is necessary during delays of more than 0.1 but
>   less than 1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating
>   directly on the data.
>
> 10 seconds is about the limit for keeping the
>   user's attention focused on the dialogue. For longer delays, users
>   will want to perform other tasks while waiting for the computer to
>   finish, so they should be given feedback indicating when the computer
>   expects to be done. Feedback during the delay is especially important
>   if the response time is likely to be highly variable, since users will
>   then not know what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a spinner. Always show the user some feedback on an action. Even if he needs to wait, he want's to know it. If you don't show anything, the user thinks theres something wrong with him or the site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the spinner, but the drawback is that the user will not be able to bookmark a selected tab because of AJAX. If instead of using AJAX, you use a form submitted (by GET) or just plain links, then it can be bookmarked properly.

Comment: you **can** bookmark, and use the tabs as pages, even with using AJAX, thanks to the `hashchange`. [An example plugin](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange), [Demo](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/)